# How do I use two different simple_form.rb initializer files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, spree

## Problem

This is a simple question, I've looked around spree forums, plataforma tec forums and SO with no success.

We want to use two separate simple_form configurations, one for our main application and another for a spree engine store we have mounted on a specific url.

## More detailed Explanation

Currently in we're developing an application using the spree engine. This means that the spree engine is mounted on a specific url and is activated by going to mysite.com/store, for example.

Now, on the main app, we're using a different set of assets than those of the spree store. Our original simple_form.rb initializer was created specifically for these assets.

Here's where it gets interesting.

Within the spree engine, we're developing a new form using simple_form as well. It works fine, but it's using the simple_form.rb file of our main app, which uses the main app's css tags and markup.

We need to modify the simple_form.rb file to actually use the spree template's css in order for things to display correctly.

## Possible solutions?

Ideally we should have a simple_form.rb file for the spree engine and one for the main app, but I haven't figured out a straight forward way of doing this...

My other idea was to have some sort of conditional in the simple_form.rb file for it to load one set of options when we're on the main app and another set of options when in the spree store... maybe checking the url?

Comment: Tried doing the URL method, but it doesn't work because the initializers only run on app startup, not during.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so apparently it is pretty obvious how to have separate configurations for simple_form.

Everything goes into a single simple_form.rb initializer. the only thing that changes is the config.wrapper.

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # Wrappers are used by the form builder to generate a
  # complete input. You can remove any component from the
  # wrapper, change the order or even add your own to the
  # stack. The options given below are used to wrap the
  # whole input.
  config.wrappers :default, :class => :input do |b|
    # config goes here
  end

  config.wrappers :special, :class => input do |b|
    # special config goes here
  end

  config.default_wrapper = :default
end
```

Then in your code, if you want to use the `:special` wrapper just write in your input like so

```
f.input :name, :wrapper => :special
```

you can find more info here

[Custom Wrappers](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers/)

Comment: Sadly, it appears Custom Wrappers only work for customizing the config for inputs (via `b.use` and `b.optional`). They don't support root-level configuration options like `config.button_class`, `config.boolean_style`, etc.